# Chain maps between short sequences and exactness

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let
$$
0 \to A_1 \to A_2 \to A_3 \to 0, ~~~~~~~~ 0 \to B_1 \to B_2 \to B_3 \to 0,
$$
two short sequences of vector spaces, and assume that there exists a chain map $F_*:A_* \to B_*$ between them (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_complex) for the definition of a chain map) such that $f_i$ is an isomorphism for each $i=1,2,3$. Is exactness of one sequence equivalent to exactness of the other, or is it possible that one exact could be exact while the other is not?

What is such a chain map called? A chain isomorphism?

Comment: The zero map is always chain map...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that each component of the chain map is assumed to be an isomorphism . . . but now that I have added this I guess the answer is clear, namely exactness of one is equivalent to exactness of the other.

Comment: Yes, it is clear in this case. But it's good that you're thinking about this: it's easy to get into the habit of thinking that any property of an object is preserved under isomorphism, and while this is true in most cases, it is not always so!

Comment: What is such a chain map called? A **chain isomorphism**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the maps are displayed as
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A_1 @>a_1>> A_2 @>{a_2}>> A_3 @>>> 0 \\
@. @V{f_1}VV @V{f_2}VV @V{f_3}VV \\
0 @>>> B_1 @>>b_1> B_2 @>>{b_2}> B_3 @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
try to prove that $f_i(\ker a_i) = \ker b_i$ and $f_{i+1}(\operatorname{im} a_i) = \operatorname{im} b_i$ for $i=1,2$.